# Check array elements and see if it contains flag my loops are not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ecmascript-6

Trying to find out that if member of `rxDetails` contain combination inside `rxInfos` of flags based on that increment counter in below scenario it should `retVlaue` `false` because logic of `for of` loop should be at member level not the complete `rxDetails` object. what is implemented wrong any help ?

main.js

```
const rxDetails = [
   {"member": 1 , "rxInfos":[
     { "firstFillIndicator": "Y", 
       "acceptDigitalFirstFill": "Y" }, 
         { "firstFillIndicator": "Y", 
       "acceptDigitalFirstFill": "Y" },
   ]},
    {"member": 2 , "rxInfos":[
     { "firstFillIndicator": "N", 
       "acceptDigitalFirstFill": "Y" }, 
         { "firstFillIndicator": "N", 
       "acceptDigitalFirstFill": "Y" },
   ]},  

 ]



 function validateOrderRequest(rxDetails) {
        let retVlaue = false;
        let firstFillCounter  = 0;
        let refillCounter = 0;
        for (const member of rxDetails) {
            for (const rx of member.rxInfos) {
                if (rx.firstFillIndicator === "Y" && rx.acceptDigitalFirstFill === "Y") {
                    firstFillCounter++;
                } else {
                    refillCounter++;
                }
            }
            if (refillCounter > 0 && firstFillCounter > 0) {
                retVlaue = true;
                return retVlaue;
            } else {
                retVlaue = false;
            }
        }

    return retVlaue;
   }

   console.log(validateOrderRequest(rxDetails));
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what your logic is. Can you please explain exactly what circumstances should return a `true` and what should return a `false`

Comment: The logic I take from your code is that you return true if there is at least one "Y", "Y" combination and at least one other combination

Comment: @KurtHamilton it will return true when `refillCounter` and `firstFillCounter` greater than 0 at member leve lbasically if any member contain FF: Y and ADFF: Y with any other combinationit will return true , problem is with multiple member when they don't have combined flags it still returns true it should return false for the `rxDetails` i have in the question

Comment: @KurtHamilton one member can have all Y or all with firstFillindicator: N thats valid scenario it should return false and thats failing its returning true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return `true` if for any given element in the array, the element has:

- At least one combination of "Y", "Y"
- At least one other combination

Your problem is that your counter is running from the start to the end of the outer array. Instead, you should move the declarations inside the first `for` loop.

Alternatively, you can simplify this a bit by using the `some` array function for your loops.

```js
validateOrderRequest(rxDetails) {
  return rxDetails.some(member => {
    let firstFillCounter  = 0;
    let refillCounter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < member.rxInfos.length; i++) {
      const rx = member.rxInfos[i];
      if (rx.firstFillIndicator === "Y" && 
          rx.acceptDigitalFirstFill === "Y") {
        firstFillCounter++;
      } else {
        refillCounter++;
      }

      if (firstFillCounter > 0 && refillCounter > 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  });
}
```

`some` will return true for the first element it finds for the condition in the callback.

In this example, the inner loop returns `true` if a member has at least one "Y", "Y" combination and at least one !"Y", !"Y" combination.

The outer `some` returns true if at least one member satisfies this condition.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read7t

Comment: exaclty  i was tryign this the counter should start inside the first for loop so it can be reset for second member it worked

Answer (score 0):

The following part looks suspicious, why would you return upon meeting one condition and not the other? Remember returning stops the execution of the rest of the script

```
if (refillCounter > 0 && firstFillCounter > 0) {
    retVlaue = true;
    return retVlaue;
} else {
    retVlaue = false;
}
```

Comment: if any member has refillCounter and firstFillCounter greater than 1 i want to stop execution but if this criteria does not meet at member level then it should return false for the function not sure why its not returning

Comment: it seems counter logic executed at parent level , how to avoid that execution

Comment: maybe because the execution is not stopped there and the loop continues.
Maybe you need to initialize `retVlaue` (typo?) inside the loop?

Comment: loop should not stopped in this case because member doesnt have combination flags